# Insert Checkbox on WooCommerce general settings page for purchase filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to create a an extra option on the `General settings` WooCommerce page but could not get that working so I tried with the `advanced tab` instead, which seem to work.

The goal here is to create a checkbox option which enables a catalog mode by applying the filter for `is_purchasable`.

But, what I cannot figure out is how to apply and save the filter for `woocommerce_is_purchasable` if the checkbox is marked the settings saved.

Here's what I got so far:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_advanced', 'catalog_mode_add_section' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_advanced', 'catalog_mode_all_settings', 10, 2 );

function catalog_mode_add_section( $sections ) {

    $sections['catalog-mode'] = __( 'Catalog Mode', 'text-domain' );
    return $sections;

}

function catalog_mode_all_settings( $settings, $current_section ) {

    if ( $current_section == 'catalog-mode' ) {
        $settings_catalog_options = array();

        // Add Title to the Settings
        $settings_catalog_options[] = array( 'name' => __( 'WooCommerce Catalog Mode', 'text-domain' ), 'type' => 'title', 'desc' => __( 'This turns WooCommerce into a catalog.', 'text-domain' ), 'id' => 'catalog_mode' );

        // Add second text field option
        $settings_catalog_options[] = array(
            'name'     => __( 'Catalog Mode', 'text-domain' ),
            'id'       => 'catalog_mode',
            'type'     => 'checkbox',
        );

        $settings_catalog_options[] = array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'catalog_mode' );
        return $settings_catalog_options;

    } else {
        return $settings;
    }
}
```

I'm lost right now..
Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your code, where each setting component need a unique identifier (`id`)… I have updated your code and your custom option is now saved.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_advanced', 'catalog_mode_add_section' );
function catalog_mode_add_section( $sections ) {
    $sections['catalog-mode'] = __( 'Catalog Mode', 'text-domain' );

    return $sections;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_advanced', 'catalog_mode_all_settings', 10, 2 );
function catalog_mode_all_settings( $settings, $current_section ) {

    if ( $current_section == 'catalog-mode' ) {

        $settings_catalog_options = array();

        // Add Title to the Settings
        $settings_catalog_options[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'WooCommerce Catalog Mode', 'text-domain' ),
            'type' => 'title',
            'desc' => __( 'This turns WooCommerce into a catalog.', 'text-domain' ),
            'id'   => 'wc_catalog_mode_title'
        );

        // Add second text field option
        $settings_catalog_options[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Catalog Mode', 'text-domain' ),
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'id'   => 'wc_catalog_mode',
        );

        $settings_catalog_options[] = array(
            'type' => 'sectionend',
            'id'   => 'wc_catalog_mode_end'
        );

        return $settings_catalog_options;
    }
    return $settings;
}
```

Then in `woocommerce_is_purchasable` and `woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable` filters, you will use it this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'product_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'product_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function product_is_purchasable_filter_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if( 'yes' === get_option('wc_catalog_mode') ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> You could use "products" section instead of "advanced" replacing your hooks with:
>
> - `woocommerce_get_sections_products`
> - `woocommerce_get_settings_products`

Comment: thank you, that is a really good breakdown of it all. Thank you.